# Jhipster UI less micro-service registration with gateway access

Tags: angular, spring-boot, jhipster

Hi I am new to Jhipster microservice configuration. I have used it before for monolithic application only.

I have already compiled and deployed registry. No problem here. But when selected gateway it asks for MySQL DB (**What is the purpose of this ?**) I am assuming probably for UAA, correct me if I am wrong.

How do I register a UI less microservice, that is I don't want any UI model to be generated in gateway but a plain microservice accessing DB.

Any pointer or help appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: A gateway is responsible for authentication, depending on which auth type you select it requires a SQL database. UI models  (for entities) in gateway are not created unless you require it, so your question is hard to understand for me. Could you clarify ? If you want a gateway without any UI, use `--skip-server` at generation time. See https://www.jhipster.tech/creating-an-app/#3

Comment: So you mean to say --skip-client which only generates server no client and --skip-server: Skip the server-side application generation, so you only have the front-end code generated. That is not what I am looking for. So can we have a Gateway without UI and authentication? We have divided our microservice architecture based on the type of service we provide so we have we will have media as a service under the gateway, all data will be one service We will provide media stream to other consumers via gateway we just want to control the assess and limit the access

Comment: Yes I meant `--skip-client` but you will still have authentication enabled as there's no option to remove it in JHipster so you must disable it manually by modifying security configuration. Also you could try to get rid of a database, there's an option for that. But if you want such a simple gateway, why do you generate it? Just create one yourself using spring cloud `@EnableZuulProxy` see https://www.baeldung.com/zuul-load-balancing

Comment: Thanks @GaëlMarziou it worked, I can see the routes at http://localhost:8080/jhipstermicroservice1/api/cars and http://localhost:8080/jhipstermicroservice2/api/cars The main reason for a gateway was if I could manage the API like I wanted http://localhost:8080/api/media-source/1 and http://localhost:8080/api/media-source/2. This what I thought we could configure with Gateway in place as it allows to manage microservice API. I have got it started now, I am exploring the same. Meantime can this be achieved ?

Comment: Yes it can be done by implementing either a custom `ServiceRouteMapper` or a Zuul filter (see Zuul doc), your routing could be based on metadata map from your services when they register as a Eureka client against the JHipster registry, this map can be set either programmatically or through applications properties under `eureka.instance.metadata-map`